# Obtaining pictures from fiddler core

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

How do i obtain pictures in fiddler core.

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate (Fiddler.Session oS) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:HTTP {1} for {2}", oS.id, oS.responseCode, oS.fullUrl);
                oS.

                // Uncomment the following two statements to decompress/unchunk the
                // HTTP response and subsequently modify any HTTP responses to replace 
                // instances of the word "Microsoft" with "Bayden"
                //oS.utilDecodeResponse(); oS.utilReplaceInResponse("Microsoft", "Bayden");
            };
```

I would expect this to be in this portion under the session portion. I am trying to replicate this effect in code.

[image]

This piece of code is obtained from the demo code in wiki

Modified the code based on the answer and this is the output

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate (Fiddler.Session oS) {
                if ((oS.responseCode == 200) && oS.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/"))
                {
                    oS.utilDecodeResponse();
                    Console.WriteLine("writing bytes");
                    Console.WriteLine(oS.requestBodyBytes);
                    // oS.responseBodyBytes is a byte[] containing the image

                    Bitmap oBMP = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(oS.responseBodyBytes));


                    // Now oBMP is an image object which contains the picture...
                }
```

URL i am refreshing on:

http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=n8LTFN1PKt2Wp_mQul4-2SAFAXQ5BD5hmxu6m7PiC56Ix7htWUtZg7YqMkzBNnmjaYZpbTGS7HG6Mw6Qss2c2qYYjrqQeAyV2lsL1MusvIe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What specifically do you mean by "obtain picture"? Something like this?

```
if ((oS.responseCode == 200) && 
    oS.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/")) 
{
  oS.utilDecodeResponse();
  // oS.responseBodyBytes is a byte[] containing the image
  Bitmap oBMP = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(oS.responseBodyBytes));
  // Now oBMP is an image object which contains the picture...
}
```

Comment: Yes I guess so. I will try to see if it works. I would like to extract the following packet as shown in the screen capture I got

Comment: Invalid parameter. It's an exception

Comment: I am having error at the bitmap line. I tried printing out the bytes using console.writeline but it appears that the byte string is empty. I am purely just refreshing the baidu page to capture the image

Comment: What is the **exact** url? In your code sample, you're incorrectly using `requestBodyBytes` instead of `responseBodyBytes`.

Comment: I have added my URL in my question

Comment: The value of interest is `oS.fullUrl`, not the HTML page.

Comment: I just want to extract all the pictures in the page. This code was taken from the demo code as I am extremely new to this Api hence I took it wholesale